# BizTalk 2006 and BizTalk 2006 R2

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2, biztalk-2006

How do I tell the 2 versions apart by looking only at their installations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open up the properties of the BTSNTSvc.exe file (by default located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2006), go to the version tab and look at the Product Name.  If it's R2, it will say so there.  If not, it will just say Microsoft BizTalk Server 2006.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can look in the registry
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\BizTalk Server\3.0**
and look for the **ProductCode_R2** key

Going by the name, I would suspect that is a keykey specific to R2.

Answer (score 2):

From the Admin Console (Platform Settings -> Adapters). If you can see any WCF adapters, you have R2...

Answer (score 0):

There is a table in the BizTalkMgmtDB - BizTalkDBVersion. If the value is v3.6.x then it is BTS2006R2, else v3.5.x is BTS2006.

Or you can use the registry - in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\BizTalk Server\3.0, there is a ProductVersionKey. Again, a value of v3.6.x tells us it is BTS2006R2.

Note: The version numbers are in the standard .NET format Major.minor.build.revision, and the build and revision are determined by SPs and cumulative updates.